# how can combine the two sqlite statements into one statement?

Tags: sqlite

```
 create  table  tmp  as select code,avg(how-low)/low  as vol  from quote group by code;
 select  avg(vol) from tmp
```

I create a new table with the first statement ,then select ave(vol) from tmp table.How can i combine the two sqlite statements into one statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need the temporary table later, use a [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH tmp AS (SELECT avg(how-low)/low AS vol
             FROM quote
             GROUP BY code)
SELECT avg(vol)
FROM tmp
```

If you have an outdated SQLite version (older than 3.8.3), you could use a subquery instead:

```
SELECT avg(vol)
FROM (SELECT avg(how-low)/low AS vol
      FROM quote
      GROUP BY code)
```